# How to stop a streaming pipeline in google cloud dataflow

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Streaming dataflow running to read the PUB/SUB subscription.

After a period of a time or may be after processing certain amount of data, i want the pipeline to stop by itself. I don't want my compute engine instance to be running indefinitely.

When i cancel the job through dataflow console, it is shown as failed job.

Is there a way to achieve this? am i missing something ? Or that feature is missing in the API.

Comment: it almost sounds like you shouldn't be running in streaming mode, but rather in batch. What's your use case that you need to run in streaming mode?

Comment: I have to streaming mode since my input is through PUB/SUB. Since streaming job is running for ever, i want to stop it

Comment: Sounds weird that you chose to design your application using pub/sub & the streaming runner, when you want it to stop after X amount of data has been processed. Sound like classic batch. Anyway, I can't see anything in the API/SDK to currently cancel the job. You could just stop/delete the VMs in the pipeline's workerpool. It would probably fail/cancel then. Would that do the trick?

Comment: We're already considering adding a variation of pub/sub source for use in batch mode, similarly to what Bharathi is suggesting ("read for a certain time" or "read a certain amount of data") - it is a valid use case that fits well with Dataflow's idea of unifying streaming and batch.

Answer (score 5):

Could you do something like this?

```
Pipeline pipeline = ...;
... (construct the streaming pipeline) ...
final DataflowPipelineJob job =
    DataflowPipelineRunner.fromOptions(pipelineOptions)
                          .run(pipeline);
Thread.sleep(your timeout);
job.cancel();
```

Comment: Ah, that's how you cancel it. I naively tried to find cancel() in the Pipeline class. Good to know.

Comment: Could you please tell me the difference between Pipeline.run() and DataflowPipelineRunner.fromOptions(pipelineOptions)
                          .run(pipeline); Is there any difference between those.

Comment: Dataflow pipelines can be run with different runners, using Pipeline.setRunner - e.g. with DirectPipelineRunner, [Blocking]DataflowPipelineRunner, and there currently exist runners on Spark and on Flink. Different runners provide different capabilities. If you just want to run the pipeline, call pipeline.run(). If you want runner-specific capabilities (e.g. DataflowPipelineRunner can cancel pipelines), configure/call the runner directly as in this example.

Comment: This solution won't be possible with new SDK 2.x because API has changed. In addition to this, streaming mode seems to be mandatory with Pub/Sub source in this SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to drain (canceling a job without losing data) a running streaming job on data flow with Rest API.

[See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50819642/4786620)

Use Rest [Update](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/update) method, with this body :

> { "requestedState": "JOB_STATE_DRAINING" }