# How to drain a java apache beam job from inside the java code?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am creating an apache beam pipeline that reads data from cloud storage and writes that data to Big Table. I want the job to stop automatically by itself when the data was fully read and written. How to accomplish that?

[How to stop a streaming pipeline in google cloud dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859829/how-to-stop-a-streaming-pipeline-in-google-cloud-dataflow)
I saw this question and there is a way to cancel the job. But this will stop before the end of the execution. How to ensure the job is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipeline you described is a batch pipeline because it read from a bounded source.

The job will automatically finish after reading all your data from GCS files and written them to BigTable.

No need to drain or stop it because it’s not a steaming job.

It will stop by itself after treating all the data.